# Getting adjusted values for every subject using an ANCOVA design in R

Tags: r

I was interested to see if there were group differences (controls and PTSD) on a memory task while controlling for depression. I ran an ANCOVA model. This was my syntax:

```
memory <- c(0.7085, 1, 0.375, 0.4585, 1, 0.8, 0.875, 0.35, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0.425, 0.8335, 1, 0.4665, 0.75, 1, 0.6665, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.5, 1, 0.7085, 0.625, 0.5835, 0.8335, 0.6, 1, 0.75, 0.4585, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6665, 0.8, 1, 0.875, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.4165)
group <- factor(c(rep("controls", 31), rep("ptsd", 13)), levels=c("controls", "ptsd"))
BDI <- c(1, 7, 0, 5, 3, 2, 4, 18, 7, 8, 0, 2, 10, 17, 1, 22, 6, 5, 4, 4, 0, 2, 4, 4, 8, 14, 4, 11, 3, 9, 11, 15, 33, 20, 31, 23, 25, 20, 21, 36, 14, 41, 22, 16)

 #ANCOVA
 Anova(lm(memory ~ BDI + group), type="III")

 #Anova Table (Type III tests)

 #Response: memory
 #            Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
 #(Intercept) 8.3847  1 148.3227 3.331e-15 ***
 #BDI         0.0951  1   1.6829    0.2018    
 #group       0.1136  1   2.0087    0.1640    
 #Residuals   2.3177 41                       
 #---
 #Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I see that there were no significant group differences on the task, p-value = 0.1640. But, I also wanted to obtain the adjusted mean for each group:

```
data         <- data.frame(group, BDI, memory)
model        <- lm(memory ~ BDI + group)
BDI.predict  <- rep(mean(BDI), 2)
data.predict <- data.frame(group = group, BDI = BDI.predict)
adjmeans     <- predict(model, data.predict)
adjmeans
```

And I see that the adjusted mean for the controls is 0.7636093 and for the ptsd group is 0.5810471.

My question is how do I obtain the adjusted value for every subject?

One of the things I want to do is see if each group performed above chance (one-sample t-test) and I want to use the adjusted values (after controlling for depression) and not the raw values.

Comment: Isn't this what the predict family of functions provides. See `?predict.lm`

Comment: No response to suggestion to use `predict`. Voting to close as vague. This seems only vaguely like a programming problem and more like a statistics question (or perhaps just something that is quickly solved by "reading the manual".)

Comment: Hi 42, I tried using predict.lm(model) and this just gave back the original values. I probably don't quite understand the usage of predict.lm(), even though I read the manual, but I'm trying to get adjusted values after controlling for depression. Would you mind giving specific code? Thank you!

Comment: I think you already have a "depression-adjusted" prediction for each subject. If what you are currently getting is not what you want then you will need to describe what you interpreation of that phrase really is. You have a prediction for what the individual might have were their BDI score at the mean for the group as a whole. The only way I can see that you might modify that would be to calculate a BDI mean for separately for each group and use that value rather than a global mean.

Comment: The mean for the original values for the memory score is 0.72 for controls and 0.67 for PTSD when I used this code: by(memory, group, mean). I used the predict.lm() method: test <- predict.lm(model) and then I got the mean again for each group: by(test, group, mean) and the means were the same with 0.72 for controls and 0.67 for PTSD. The adjusted means should be 0.7636093 for the controls and 0.5810471 for the ptsd group.

Comment: Does the OP have a conclusion now?

Answer (score 1):

John Fox's `effects` package will deliver that answer for you:

```
 library (effects)
 help(pac=effects)
 mod.dat <- lm(memory ~ BDI + group,
     data=data)
 mod.dat <- lm(memory ~ BDI + group,
     data=data)
 eff.dat <- allEffects(mod.dat, xlevels=list(group=c("controls","ptsd") ))
 eff.dat
#----- output
 model: memory ~ BDI + group

 BDI effect
BDI
        0        10        20        30        40 
0.6241901 0.6975066 0.7708231 0.8441396 0.9174561 

 group effect
group
 controls      ptsd 
0.7636093 0.5810471
```

This is the "group" part of the content of the `eff.dat` ojbect that contains the values which the `print.eff` function is delivering:

str(eff.dat) # then snipped out the first part:

```
$ group:List of 21
  ..$ term                   : chr "group"
  ..$ formula                :Class 'formula'  language memory ~ BDI + group
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ response               : chr "memory"
  ..$ variables              :List of 1
  .. ..$ group:List of 3
  .. .. ..$ name     : chr "group"
  .. .. ..$ is.factor: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ levels   : chr [1:2] "controls" "ptsd"
  ..$ fit                    : num [1:2, 1] 0.764 0.581
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
```

So if you wanted those as a vector just address the list by name:

```
> eff.dat$group$fit
       [,1]
1 0.7636093
2 0.5810471
```

Comment: This is a much simpler way to do what I initially did, thank you! However, I'm a newbie to the R environment and reading the packages. What command would I enter to get the adjusted values for every subject?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would there be "adjusted values" for each subject. Adjustment implies some sort of grouping.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's my lack of understanding about how the adjusted means are calculated, but to get the adjusted means don't there have to be individual values to get the mean for each group?